# cannot get the user's profile picture from the user ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

No matter how much delay I give it this part just returns:

> Error: Image given has not completed loading

I tried making a custom leaderboard using `canvas` and it should've returned an image with my own pfp inside a square I coded in canvas

```js
let image_source = `./leaderboard.png`

let user = client.users.fetch('537279767108648991')
let bg = new Image()
bg.src = image_source
let av = new Image()
var image_user = []

user.then(function(value) {
  image_user = value.displayAvatarURL({
    extension: `png`,
    dynamic: true,
    format: `png`
  })
})
av.src = image_user

setTimeout(() => {
  if (av.complete == true) {
    canvas_()
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Discord API so I can't diagnose the exact problem, however I can tell you that `av.src = image_user` absolutely needs to be within the `user.then()` block.